# Alock is not launched when specified in crontab

Tags: cron

I have the following problem: I am going to run a TV dashboard basing on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal with transparent screensaver and with locking feature enabled. In my configuration, I used activated caffeine + alock package. When I am running at system startup the following command:

`alock -bg none -auth pam`

the dashboard system is starting fine and is secured well, waiting for any key press as expected. However, when I want to unlock the screen to do something and let's say, I will forget to lock the system after, according to company policy screen should be locked again after 15mins. To achieve that, I created the following entry in /etc/crontab:

`*/15 * * * * <<user-name>> alock -bg none -auth pam`

For some reason, nothing happens then. I tried to reload cron service (unnecessarily), but it didn't help. Also, I tried to add a full path to alock, changed with root as executor, tried with special privileges like setuid...nothing from these resolved my problem.

Does someone has some hint, any idea, how to implement it?

Comment: It seems to be [this application](https://github.com/Arkq/alock). Its README says "It is just for locking current X session". There is no current X session in the cron environment, therefore this fails. You need to find a tool that permits specifying the X session.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same package for alock. I didn't took into consideration the fact about X-session as it is. For the other tools, this might be a problem because from security perspective some applications we have approved, for some there was no requests to review - hence, I would wait a bit of time to have other tool reviewed. It seems that at this moment, the current workaround would be to force users to reboot the machine once they finished the work or create a shortcut with alock command on hand.